# Athena pagination and performance issue

Tags: sql, query-optimization, amazon-athena

I have huge data set in S3 and using AWS Athena I am trying to query it, below 3 parameters are input for my query.

1. marketplaceId
2. startIndex
3. endIndex

but it's took 16 seconds to query just 50 records. ( I am using python to query data from Athena --> S3)
What I am doing wrong here? and the way I implemented pagination is right or not?

**SQL Query  which I am executing.**

```
SELECT 
  dataset_date, 
  marketplace_id, 
  gl_product_group, 
  gl_product_group_desc, 
  browse_node_id, 
  browse_node_name, 
  root_browse_node_id, 
  browse_root_name, 
  wt_xref_id, 
  gt_xref_id, 
  node_path, 
  total_count_of_asins, 
  buyable_asin_count, 
  glance_view_count_t12m, 
  ord_cnt, 
  price_p50, 
  price_p90, 
  price_p100, 
  row_num 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      dataset_date, 
      marketplace_id, 
      gl_product_group, 
      gl_product_group_desc, 
      browse_node_id, 
      browse_node_name, 
      root_browse_node_id, 
      browse_root_name, 
      wt_xref_id, 
      gt_xref_id, 
      node_path, 
      total_count_of_asins, 
      buyable_asin_count, 
      glance_view_count_t12m, 
      ord_cnt, 
      price_p50, 
      price_p90, 
      price_p100, 
      row_number() over (
        order by 
          browse_node_id, 
          gl_product_group, 
          glance_view_count_t12m desc
      ) as row_num 
    from 
      (
        select 
          * 
        from 
          category_info 
        WHERE 
          marketplace_id = '<marketplaceId>'
      )
  ) 
WHERE 
  row_num between '<startIndex>' 
  and '<endIndex>';
```

**Update**

After debugging my issue with timestamp I found It's taking 6 second for 1 query. and I am running two query.
1st - to get data , query which I mentioned above.
2nd - to get count of total number or rows in my table.

so that's why it's taking 12-16 sec.
So is there any way to get total number of rows without second query (select count(*) from category_info).

Comment: _"but it's took 16 seconds to query just 50 records"_ - do you mean that `category_info` has only 50 records or  that the query is returning only 50 records? If the latter (and based on _"I have huge data set"_ it is) then it does not sound slow (depending on total number of items in the table, especially if table is not partitioned by `marketplace_id`) - for every such query Athena needs to go through all the records to filter out `marketplace_id` and calculate `row_num`.

Comment: @GuruStron

I found root cause, I am running two query 1 to get data and 2nd to get count total number of rows.

both are taking approx 6 seconds.
6*2 = 12 sec.

Now is there any way to get total number of rows without second query 
(select count(*) from category_info).